# What is optimize.portfolio.rebalancing in R-package PortfolioAnalytics calculating?

Tags: r, portfolio-optimization, rebalancing

I recently started using the R-package `PortfolioAnalytics` for performing some portfolio optimization. And I'm trying to get a grasp on what exactly the function `optimize.portfolio.rebalancing` is calculating. In particular, I'm wondering why the weights calculated (from the second period onwards) are different than the ones that I get when directly calling `optimize.portfolio`.

I was under the impression that `optimize.portfolio.rebalancing` was basically a "wrapper around `optimize.portfolio`" (from the manual), so I thought that the function simply calls `optimize.portfolio` repeatedly for periods of length `rolling_window`. But then, shouldn't the results be identical to what a manual call of `optimize.portfolio` with the exact same periods yields? Or is `optimize.portfolio.rebalancing` performing some additional calculations? What am I missing?

Here's a minimal example illustrating my question:

```
data("edhec")
returns <- edhec[, 1:4]
funds <- colnames(returns)

portfolio <- portfolio.spec(assets = funds)
portfolio <- add.constraint(portfolio = portfolio, type = "full_investment")
portfolio <- add.constraint(portfolio = portfolio, type = "long_only")
portfolio <- add.objective(portfolio = portfolio, type = "risk", name = "ES")

portfolio.rebalanced <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(R = returns,
                                                       portfolio = portfolio,
                                                       optimize_method = "ROI",
                                                       rebalance_on = "quarters",
                                                       training_period = 12,
                                                       rolling_window = 12)

# check, if optimize.portfolio gives the same results: first period
portfolio.optimized <- optimize.portfolio(R = returns["::1997-12-31",],
                                          portfolio = portfolio,
                                          optimize_method = "ROI")
portfolio.optimized
portfolio.rebalanced$opt_rebalancing$`1997-12-31`
# YES!

# but: last period
portfolio.optimized <- optimize.portfolio(R = returns["2006-08-31::2009-08-31",],
                                          portfolio = portfolio,
                                          optimize_method = "ROI")
portfolio.optimized
portfolio.rebalanced$opt_rebalancing$`2009-08-31`
# NO! What's wrong?
```

Comment: I'm thinking that if it's rolling window and not expanding window, it might drop the later observations and take into account only the 12 latest ones...I will simulate something and check it :)

Comment: What other libraries do you use? I'm getting errors if I run the same code
Error: "package:ROI" %in% search() || requireNamespace("ROI", quietly = TRUE) is not TRUE

Comment: Forgot to mention the required libraries: quantmod, PerformanceAnalytics, PortfolioAnalytics and ROI are loaded. Also, ROI.plugin.glpk and ROI.plugin.quadprog. Not sure, which of these are really necessary.

Comment: As to it only taking into account the latest 12 observations... yes, that's what I'm expecting. And this is what I'm trying to do manually by calculating `"2006-08-31::2009-08-31"` (3 years, so 12 quarters, right?). It works for the first period, but not from the second period onwards (check the periods in `portfolio.rebalanced$opt_rebalancing$...`), so I'm thinking the following periods are adjusted in some way.

Comment: I think its data feed, because if you put rebalance on 'quarters', it takes as end points only end of March, June,... and you are checking it against end of August...so try to change that to 2009-08-31..also you should have only 12 months training, so not from 2006, but 2008? 

Would dig deeper, but I still cant make it work:D , it says: Error: paste0("package:", plugin) %in% search() || requireNamespace(plugin,  .... is not TRUE

it is something wrong with the ROI...

Comment: I'm checking it against end of August, as this is one of the periods listed under attribute `portfolio.rebalanced$opt_rebalancing$...`, so I'm thinking this is one of the endpoints used. But that's a good suggestion, I will try that.
Also, I think, setting `rebalance_on` to `quarters` and `training_period` to 12 means, it rebalances using periods of length 12 (quarters), but does so every quarter.

Comment: As to getting it to work: The same errors appeared here, too. Basically means that some plugin that is used by the procedure is not installed. I managed to make it work by installing everything around the ROI plugin: So, `ROI` itself, of course, and `ROI.plugin.glpk` and `ROI.plugin.quadprog`. And, just in case, `Rglpk` and `quadprog`, but I'm not really sure, if all of these are needed.
Anyway, thanks for trying. :)

Answer (score 1):

It rebalances on endpoints(R), you passed it quarters, so every quarter as determined by endpoints(returns,'quarters') it will rebalance using the last 12 observations.

In your case there you called optimize portfolio on a dataset of 37 observations

```
     nrow(edhec["2006-08-31::2009-08-31"]) 
[1] 37
```

This should explain the discrepancy between the two calls as one has a dataset of 12 vs 37.

While in your first test you called optimize portfolio on a dataset of 12 observations which in line with the optimize.portfolio.rebalancing call

```
nrow(edhec["::1997-12-31",])
[1] 12
```